# Backwards quote marks in Latex (and I've tried a lot of things to prevent it!)

Tags: csquotes, quotation

I am aware this question has been asked several times before but I am still yet to find a answer that seems to work for me.

I have used `csquotes` package to try and get proper quote marks but I do not end up with proper quote marks and they are still the wrong way round. Using `` ` `` also does not work.

It must be something in my package class which is stopping it from working. I am using a Doctoral Thesis LaTeX class which I am aware is hand coded but does anyone know what other packages might be preventing me from obtaining proper quote marks?

This is what I keep getting:

[image: This is what I keep getting]

But the front quote mark is still backwards. I've tried so many things and nothing seems to work which makes me think some other package is preventing it.

Any ideas?!

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which font family is loaded by your document. A Palatino clone, by any chance? Please also tell us which language-related options you employ, both for the document as a whole and in conjunction with the `csquotes` package.

Comment: The quote looks okay for english and palatino. I get this too, seems to be the font design.

Comment: A separate observation: There are several "Doctoral Thesis" LaTeX document classes out there, in the wild. Which one of these might you be using? Is the class file online somewhere?

Comment: Ah yes sorry I'm poor at writing these questions! I'm using \usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} and I use British with babel package. And yes Palatino! I use mathpazo package. I also use inputenc for international characters and fontec too. Base class is book. Does that help?

Comment: Hmmm I found the class years ago...let me have a quick look!

Comment: \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\newcommand{\classname}{DoctoralThesis}
\ProvidesClass{\classname}[2017/08/27 v1.6 LaTeXTemplates.com]

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But when it's double quotes it looks really tacky...! Surely can't be the font...

Comment: The quotes are the expected shape.  Can you give a link or a reference to what you expect to see?

Comment: Ahh yea you guys might be right! I guess I was hoping for something looking like what I've just added above, but with single quotes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quotes of the font looks like this. That's the font design.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\enquote*{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]